# Why is the Authentication object of the SecurityContext not shared across threads?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-security

I am having the problem of sometimes getting a `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException`. At the moment I believe that this is a threading issue. According to another question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376320/spring-security-same-securitycontext-instance-in-multiple-threadlocals-how-doe)) the `SecurityContext` is passed through the `HttpSession` object between different threads - but for some reason this is not working for me.

This is how I am handling the login at the moment:

```
public ShopAdminDTO login(String userEmail, String password) throws EmailAddressNotFoundException {

    LOGGER.debug("Login request for " + userEmail);

    // Create and initialize user details object for Spring Security authentication mechanism.
    ShopAdminUserDetails userDetails = new ShopAdminUserDetails(userEmail, password, true, true, true, true, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

    // Create authentication object for the Spring SecurityContext
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

    boolean requiresEmailActivation = this.shopAdminValidationTokenRepository.getRequiresEmailValidation(userEmail);

    if(requiresEmailActivation == true) {

        LOGGER.info("Login denied: Email is not validated yet.");

        // IMPORTANT NOTE: We throw an EmailNotFoundException instead of a
        // PleaseValidateYourEmailFirstException in order to NOT reveal
        // that this email exists. So: Do not "FIX" this!
        throw new EmailAddressNotFoundException();
    }

    LOGGER.debug("Email appears validated.");

    try {
        // Execute authentication chain to try user authentication
        auth = this.adminAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(auth);
    } catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
        // FIXME Login: We could/should count and limit login attempts here?
        LOGGER.info("Bad credentials found for: " + userEmail);
        throw e;
    }

    LOGGER.info("User successfully authenticated [userEmail="+userEmail+"]");

    // Set the authentication to the SecurityContext, the user is now logged in
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);


    // Finally load the user data
    ShopAdminDTO shopAdminDto = this.shopAdminRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);
    return shopAdminDto;
}
```

This is the **applicationContext-security.xml** file

```
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- // BEGIN Spring Security -->

<sec:http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"/>

<bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
    <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationListener" class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationListener"/>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator"
      class="com.mz.server.web.auth.permission.CustomPermissionEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String"
             value-type="com.mz.server.web.auth.permission.Permission">
            <entry key="isTest" value-ref="testPermission"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="testPermission" class="com.mz.server.web.auth.permission.TestPermission">
</bean>

<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>

<sec:global-method-security 
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">     
    <sec:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>       
</sec:global-method-security>

<!-- // END Spring Security -->
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
```

What fails is this part of the `AbstractSecurityInterceptor#beforeInvocation` function:

```
if (debug) {
    logger.debug("Secure object: " + object + "; Attributes: " + attributes);
}

if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
    credentialsNotFound(messages.getMessage(
            "AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticationNotFound",
            "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"),
            object, attributes);
}

Authentication authenticated = authenticateIfRequired();
```

Where it calls `credentialsNotFound` because `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is `null`.

---

Comparing a failing stack trace from the *first* login after booting up the server:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.servlet.LoginServletImpl - Login request by userId: user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.LoginService - Login request for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.LoginService - Email appears validated.. authenticating..
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.mz.server.spring.auth.AdminAuthenticationProvider - authenticate(), User email: user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - findByUserEmail(): user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - User found.
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Loading password salt for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Checking password for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Password valid.
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - getPrincipal()
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - Setting user com.mz.server.spring.auth.ShopAdminUserDetails@8ac733b2: Username: user@gmx.at; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities to 'authenticated'.
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO  com.mz.server.service.LoginService - User successfully authenticated [userEmail=user@gmx.at]
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - findByUserEmail(): user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - User found.
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - Requested available shops.
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@259bee56: Authentication: com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication@259bee56
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List com.mz.server.service.ShopService.getAvailableShops(); target is of class [com.mz.server.service.ShopService]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'isAuthenticated()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomHttpSessionListener - AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundEvent
Jun 09, 2016 8:06:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List com.mz.shared.web.service.shop.ShopServlet.getAvailableShops()' threw an unexpected exception: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:416)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
....
```

to a working stack trace:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.servlet.LoginServletImpl - Login request by userId: user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.LoginService - Login request for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.LoginService - Email appears validated.. authenticating..
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.spring.auth.AdminAuthenticationProvider - authenticate(), User email: user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - findByUserEmail(): user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - User found.
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Loading password salt for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Checking password for user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Password valid.
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - getPrincipal()
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - Setting user com.mz.server.spring.auth.ShopAdminUserDetails@8ac733b2: Username: user@gmx.at; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities to 'authenticated'.
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.service.LoginService - User successfully authenticated [userEmail=user@gmx.at]
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - findByUserEmail(): user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - User found.
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - Requested available shops.
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@1ea22883: Authentication: com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication@1ea22883
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl - 
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List com.mz.server.service.ShopService.getAvailableShops(); target is of class [com.mz.server.service.ShopService]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'isAuthenticated()', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - isAuthenticate(): true
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication@1ea22883
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@653fccd, returned: 1
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.ShopService - Getting available shops for ..
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.spring.auth.CustomUserAuthentication - getPrincipal()
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.service.ShopService - user@gmx.at
[http-bio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG com.mz.server.repository.jooq.shop.ShopAdminRepository - Fetching shops for shop_admin_id 1
```

We can see that the difference is that the first stacktrace is produced by *two* threads `[http-bio-8080-exec-4]` and `[http-bio-8080-exec-6]`. I see this behavior quite often that the thread name changes and then this exception comes up. So this appears to be a multithreading issue

---

This is the entire **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>mz | life</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mz.server.BootstrappingServerConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mz.server.servlet.app.ApplicationDataServletImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/application</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mz.server.servlet.LoginServletImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>shop</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopServletImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>shop</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/shop</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>shopadmin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mz.server.servlet.shop.ShopAdminServletImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>shopadmin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/shopadmin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 
        XSRF-Token Servlet 
    -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/xsrf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 
        This is the name of the session cookie set by the Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat or Jetty) 
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>gwt.xsrf.session_cookie_name</param-name>
        <param-value>JSESSIONID</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mobile-restapi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mobile-restapi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/restapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web-restapi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/context/applicationContext-restapi.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web-restapi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/classes/context/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you know, what resource the different requests tried to access in the first place? How do you serve static content? Could it be possible that one of the threads tries to access some protected resource (image/css) from the login page?

Comment: @StefanHaberl Well, this request you're seeing the log from comes from the click on the login button. This is not really doing more than looking into the database and check if the password is correct for the given username. See the `User successfully authenticated [userEmail=user@gmx.at]` entry which tells me that the login was actually working. So no, there are no additional resources involved in this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and simply changed it to that:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also removed

```
<sec:http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" />
```

in my applicationContext-spring.xml and I added this alias

```
<alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain"/>
```

The final applicationContext-spring.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd"    
    >

    <!-- Imports -->
    <import resource="applicationContext-spring-acl.xml"/>

    <bean id="authenticationListener" class="com.mahlzeit.server.spring.auth.CustomAuthenticationListener"/>

    <bean id="httpSessionListener" class="com.mahlzeit.server.spring.auth.CustomHttpSessionListener"/>

    <bean id="adminAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mahlzeit.server.spring.auth.AdminAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="dslContext" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mahlzeit.server.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="adminAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Filter Chain -->

    <bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'/>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    </bean>

    <alias name="filterChainProxy" alias="springSecurityFilterChain"/>

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I took [this](https://gist.github.com/leonelag/3833258) as reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can transfer the SecurityContext from one Thread to another

```
Runnable originalRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // invoke secured service
}
};
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable wrappedRunnable =
    new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(originalRunnable, context);

new Thread(wrappedRunnable).start();
```

See Concurrency Support

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

You have [`allowSessionCreation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html#setAllowSessionCreation(boolean)) set to `false`.

*Note that setting this flag to false does not prevent this class from storing the security context. If your application (or another filter) creates a session, then the security context will still be stored for an authenticated user.*

are you creating a session correctly? and or do you really want security not to create sessions?

Comment: Hi! Wow, interesting :D I think I got that from a tutorial quite a while ago. I *think* I want Spring Security to create sessions I guess. I want to login a user and let it send requests as it likes during the session. Why would anyone not want to have sessions? I am not sure if I am correctly creating sessions myself but I will try but I will set `allowSessionCreation` to `true` as soon as I got home and let you know if this worked.

Comment: I've tried setting it to `true` but it's still the same. The moment a different thread comes in I am getting the exception.

Comment: can you post any other related configs?  eg, web.xml

Comment: how are you starting up this app?

Comment: I have added the web.xml to my question. What do you mean with "*how*"? It's running in a Servlet container - Tomcat/Jetty.